# Make byebug stay in scope/function after running last line

Tags: ruby, debugging, byebug

Say I'm debugging a function like this

```
def foo {
  byebug
  x = 1+1
}
```

Running this, we hit the breakpoint. If I now hit "n", it runs the next line and exits the function. How can I instead remain in the function and inspect `x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `finish 0`.

The `finish` command should step out the number of frames you specify as an argument. If you specify `0`, it has special behavior and just finishes the current frame without stepping out of it.

Comment: Thanks @deivid. This works in a standalone Ruby file, but for some reason didn't work in Rails (a model class called from a test case). Any idea why?

Comment: Can you try that using ruby-head. It includes some unreleased TracePoint API bugs.

Comment: Bug fixes, I mean. :)

Comment: Actually just updating to 2.1.3 (from 2.1.1) made it work now. This will be useful, thanks.

Comment: 2.1.3. I had rvm on 2.1.* in this env.

Comment: Ah, ok. Just asking because the latest patch level version in the 2.1 series is 2.1.7 and it also includes TracePoint API bug fixes over 2.1.3